# Construct a List with all buttons with similar title values using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using C# in Visual Basic to construct a List that is full of IWebElements that are gathered using XPath. I will click() on each of the buttons.

What I have so far, is this:

```
List<IWebElement> buttonlist =  
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@title='Quick Apply']"));
```

the html of the buttons is as follows:

```
<button class="job_tool job_apply default" data-interview="0" 
data-    oneclick="0" data-contact="" data-job="0" 
data-href="the url" rel="tooltip" **title="Quick Apply"** 
aria-describedby="">Quick Apply</button>
```

The titles of all the buttons are the same, "Quick Apply". How can I make a list to then click on all of the buttons?

Comment: What happens when you click one of these buttons?

Comment: It sends a ping to the website, and the text changes. It doesn't take you to  a new page or anything.

Comment: Did you get an error? Whats the issue?

Comment: The error says that I can't define it as a List, but of a ReadOnlyCollection. So I made it into that, and now it other parts of my code broke.

Comment: may i know logic/code used to click on buttons after collecting this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the return value of `FindElements` directly :

```
var buttons = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@title='Quick Apply']"));
foreach (IWebElement button in buttons)
{
    button.Click();
}
```

Or if you really want to make a `List<IWebElement>` out of it :

```
var buttons = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@title='Quick Apply']"));
var list = new List<IWebElement>(buttons);
```